# Avoid duplicate entry in xml file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

I am trying to restrict duplicate entry to an XML file and below is the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Info>
<Details>
<ID>Ryan</ID>
</Details>
<Details>
<ID>Danny</ID>
</Details>
</Info>
```

Now if I try to add Ryan or Danny again to the ID I should alert like user name already exists.

I'm using the below code and it doesn't work. `strName` is a string and has username value to be added. Can anyone provide suggestions?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Info.xml"));
bool userExistsAlready = xDoc.Descendants("Details").Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == strName);
if (userExistsAlready)
{
    //alert
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
bool userExistsAlready = xDoc.Descendants("Details")
                             .Elements("ID")
                             .Any(x => x.Value == "Ryan");
```

The problem with your code is that it tries to access *attribute* `ID`. But `ID` is in fact another XML element contained inside element `<Details>`.

Comment: how can I check another elements called `department` with and condition. I tried few codes and couldn't get it.

Comment: bool usertExists = xDocss.Descendants("Details").Elements("ID").Any(x => x.Value == Name) &&                    xDocss.Descendants("Details").Elements("Password").Any(y => y.Value == Pwd);

Comment: @vicky Well, that's another question. It is discouraged answering questions in comments. Try writing a different post with the relevant XML file.

Comment: I am getting used to it and sure will post them new.

Answer (score 0):

You could set ID as an attribute of Details and then check if that entry exist using the XmlDocument method GetElementByID, or implement a for cycle that checks out the property InnerText of every element in the array resulting from the call to GetElementsByName method.